# Delete rows with duplicates in first column and only keep the one with most recent date in second column

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with records like this:

```
ID  column1  column2     column3
1   23566    2016-03-12  2016-03-24
2   23566    2016-05-11  2016-06-14
3   24532    2016-01-02  2016-01-04
```

I would like to delete the rows that have duplicate values in the first column and only keep the one with the most recent date in the second column.
Like so:

```
ID  column1  column2     column3
1   23566    2016-05-11  2016-06-14
2   24532    2016-01-02  2016-01-04
```

Comment: You can use a cte with row_number and then delete where row_number > 1. If you can provide some details about your tables I can show you what I mean.

Answer (score 2):

You can use row_number to get duplicate and delete

```
;WITH cte
AS (SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date DESC) rn
FROM yourtable)
DELETE FROM cte
WHERE rn > 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a CTE with `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT t.*, RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Col1 ORDER BY Col2 DESC)
   FROM dbo.TableName t
)
DELETE FROM CTE WHERE RN > 1
```

If you want to know what you're going to delete change the `DELETE` to a `SELECT *`